# Force Mathematica to write expression with standard operations

Tags: replacement

I've the following expression in Mathematica:  **myExp = a^3 b^3**

If I impose a ReplaceAll with command **/.** in to replace **a b** by **c**, I expect to see **c^3**. Note that we could rewrite a^3 b^3 as a * a * a * b * b * b, but Mathematica rewrites it as Times[Power[a,3],Power[b,3]]. For that reason, when I try to use the command **myExp /. {a b -> c}**, it does not replace anything and returns the original expression a^3 b^3.

I managed to force Mathematica to not use the Power as follows:

```
Unprotect[Power];  
Format[Power[a_, n_Integer?Positive]] := 
 Distribute[ConstantArray[Hold[a], n], Hold, List, HoldForm, Times]
Protect[Power];
```

It returns **(a a a) (b b b)**, which is simple Times[(a a a),(b b b)]. Even in that format, it does not replace a b by c.

I need to make Mathematica NOT use Power and Times to make such a replacement. Technically, the expression a^3 b^3 (i.e. Times[Power[a,3],Power[b,3]], should be represented simply as a * a * a * b * b * b (i.e., a a a b b b) to make it work.

Does anyone in the forum already have this problem? I don't know if rewriting it is the correct way to do this replacement or if there is another way to impose a change in the intrinsic tree of Mathematica.

**Long story short,** I need that the command **myExp /. {a b -> c}** gives **c^3** as result.

Thank you very much,

Best wishes.

Comment: Would `FullSimplify[myExp, Assumptions -> (c == a b)]` be sufficient?

Comment: PolynomialReduce is intended for such purposes.

Comment: @rhermans This solution works in some cases. If you have a big or complicated expression, Simplify or FullSimplify simply aren't able to give a simplified expression even if you leave it running for hours. That's why the replacement using /. is interesting to help the solver. My idea is to make some replacements and then simplify afterwards.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I looked at this function and I didn't see how to use it in this case.

Comment: For algebraic manipulation, it is usually better to use algebraic operators than expression-restructuring operators like `ReplaceAll`. That said, replacement rules with a single symbol on left hand side usually works.

Comment: Like so: `In[228]:= PolynomialReduce[a^3*b^3, c - a*b, {a, b}][[2]]

Out[228]= c^3`

Answer (score 4):

The standard easy trick to get what you want is to make a replacement another way around. Instead of the rule `a b->c` do `a->c/b`. Like follows:

```
myExp = a^3 b^3

(*  a^3 b^3  *)

myExp /. a -> c/b

(*   c^3   *)
```

In some more complex cases, one can automate this a bit using `Solve`. I show it within the same simple example, but one typically applies it when the right replacement is not that evident:

```
sol = Solve[a*b == c, a][[1, 1]]

(*  a -> c/b  *)

myExp /. sol

(*   c^3   +)
```

**Edit**:

To address your question. In those cases when one needs to make a replacement everywhere where the variable `a` stays, the direct substitution of the sort I have introduced is useful.

There are, however, situations where in different subexpressions involving `a` one needs to make different substitutions. Let me give a simple example. Suppose we have

```
expr1 = ((a - b)^2 + a^2 b^2) /((a - b)^2 - a^2 b^2)
```

and we want to transform it into

```
(x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 - y^2)
```

It is quite clear that in this case, the replacements like

```
    expr1 /. a -> x + b
    expr1 /. a -> y/b
    
  (*  (x^2 + b^2 (b + x)^2)/(x^2 - b^2 (b + x)^2)
    
    (y^2 + (-b + y/b)^2)/(-y^2 + (-b + y/b)^2)  *)
```

do not bring us to the desired result. The following, however, does the job:

```
expr1 /. a^2 b^2 -> y^2 /. a -> x + b

(*  (x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 - y^2)  *)
```

A little bit another way is to apply the "standard" approach but make the replacement a bit more precise. To do this, let us first determine the positions of the terms `a^2*b^2`:

```
pos1 = Position[expr1, a^2 b^2][[1]]

pos2 = Position[expr1, -a^2 b^2][[1]]
(*  {2,2}
{1,1,2}    *)
```

Now let us make the first standard replacement directly in those positions, and only then the second standard replacement - in the rest of the expression:

```
MapAt[ReplaceAll[#, a -> y/b] &, expr1, {pos1, pos2}] /. a -> x + b

(*  (x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 - y^2)  *)
```

One can apply a few other tricks. To summarize, one needs here a certain flexibility.

Have fun!

Comment: Interesting approach Alexei. I'm trying here but it doesn't look to work for long expressions. I'll keep searching for it.

Comment: @Isaías Faria Silva If you would like to have a universal function to do that, I have bad news: there is no such a universal function or such an approach. It is exactly the place where science transforms into art. That is, in some expressions you choose this way, in others a different one. Your choice depends on the expression.

Comment: @IsaíasFariaSilva it would improve your question if you can update/edit with an example where this standard solution does not work.

Comment: @Isaías Faria Silva Please see the edit.